# gutenberg core/columns attributes via function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Gutenberg - Grid layout & attributes

After the images and the galleries I am trying to modify the grid output.

I have to recover "how many columns has the grid" but I can't open the array or point to the right attribute / value.

```
  //// Change WordPress gutenberg grid
  add_filter( 'render_block', 'GutenGrid' , 10, 2 );
  function GutenGrid( $block_content, $block )
  {

    if ( $block['blockName'] === 'core/columns' )
    {

      return  print_r( $block['attrs']['columns'] );

    }
  }
```

how do i know the amount of cols in the grid?

Thank

Answer (score 1):

ok... stupid wordpress... I just found out that gutenberg doesn't mark columns less than 2.

So if it is <=2 no necklace remains. 1 and 2 represent  a basic quantity (therefore 
null), from 3 onwards it returns how many columns are.